# How might ARP impact the UDP communication and what is a scenario i can reproduce to check/understand it?

Tags: arp, udp

I was wondering which impact the ARP protocoll might have on a UDP communication. I am learning for an exam and trying things out with mininet (linux )/ wireshark to understand the dependencys between protocols etc and was wondering how these two might impact.

Comment: ARP and UDP have nothing to do with each other. ARP is used to resolve a destination network protocol (IPv4) address to a destination data-link address, while UDP is a transport protocol that knows nothing about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering which impact the ARP protocoll might have on a UDP communication.

None.

Any IPv4 communication in a MAC-based network (like the ubiquitous Ethernet) requires knowledge of the destination's MAC address, usually learned via ARP. Beyond that, there is no direct connection between UDP and ARP.

The application uses UDP to send data. UDP encapsulates the data in a datagram and submits it to IP. IP encapsulates the UDP datagram in a packet and submits it to the data link layer. The data link layer requires the MAC address, so IP uses ARP to learn it.